# Backpatching with OR_ELSE and ALSO in yacc

Tags: c, yacc

I am trying to implement Syntax Directed Translation(SDT) using yacc. In the case of boolean expressions I've chosen to adopt Backpatching method. Below is an example of my implementation of logical OR using C in yacc :

```
simpleexp : simpleexp OR M simpleexp
  {
    backpatch($1.falselist,$3.quad);
    $$.truelist = merge($1.truelist,$4.truelist);
    $$.falselist = $4.falselist;
    $$.type = TYPE_BOOL;
    fprintf(fout, "Rule 64 \t\t simpleexp -> simpleexp OR simpleexp \n");
  };
  M : /* empty */ 
  {
    $$.quad = nextquad();//nextquad returns next available place in quadruples array
  };
```

It does work but my current problem is something else. We are to have an alternate approach for handling logical operation OR_ELSE besides the "Side Effect" approach adopted just for usual OR. Lets go on a little bit more about the problem

Imagine we are dealing with something like simpleexp1 OR simpleexp2(numbers are provided in order to distinct simpleexp s from each other). Using the implemetation of logical OR , as implemented above , we won't evaluate simpleexp2 if simpleexp1 is true. Because we should jump to simpleexp1.truelist which is filled via calling backpatch function called somewhere else later. In case of simpleexp1 OR_ELSE simpleexp2 we want to be sure that simpleexp2 is evaluated , whether the final result will be true or false. For example if simpleexp2 is (x++ == 4) where x is an integer , we want to be sure that the incrementation takes place and the value of x increments by 1 ; however , in the case of simpleexp1 OR simpleexp2 , the value of x won't change if the simpleexp1 is true.

P.S. : I have figured out that in order the simpleexp2 to be evaluated we should fill both the truelist and falselist of simpleexp1 in an order that causes the control flow to be given to the beginning of simpleexp2 , but I don't know what to do next!